# Correct usage of jQuery to select each closest section, and a bit about semantic

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, semantic-markup

I currently work on an portfolio-overview, the client wants a slideable (toggle-stated) section below each row. The section will be filled later with some *ajaxed* stuff, depending on which link was clicked.

The problem is, that jQuery's `closest()`-selector not work (The fault is certainly not in jQuery's core, rather than my approach :P).

Currently I use jQuery's `next`-selector, but this works **only** on **each 4th** `a`-tag. I'm working on jsfiddle to prototype a bit around: *http://fiddle.jshell.net/k79kf/1/*

Any ideas what's the problem?

---

Another thing is the semantic correctness of what I made. Actual I've some `a`-nodes to toggle the section below each row, four in number:

```
a a a a
section
a a a a
section
a a a a
section
...
```

However, I think it is not the *"proper"* way to do this, or? Maybe is an ordered-list the better choice, but where to place the slideable section. Or `section`'s instead of `a`'s and `article`'s instead of `section`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest()` selects the closest *ancestor*.

`next()` selects only the immediate next sibling.

You want `.nextAll('section').first()`.

---

A more semantic approach would be to wrap each group of four in a container element, then write `$(this).parent().children('section')`.

Alternatively, give each section an ID, make the `a`s point to that ID (`<a href="#section1">`), then write `$(this.id)`.
Using this approach, you can even eliminate the Javascript entirely using a `section:target` CSS selector.

Comment: Great :-* I played with `nextAll` already around but haven't select the first section. Thanks!